# Warning Message: Gas Requirement: Compiling Multiple contracts Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, gas-price

I am getting following warning message while compiling the test contract on Remix IDE :

> Gas requirement of function Test.send(address) high: infinite. If the
> gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it
> cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions
> that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying
> arrays in storage)

//Test contract giving warning Message

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./Another.sol";

contract Test {
    function send(address another) public  {
        Another(another).sendToAnother();
    }
}
```

==
Another contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Another {
    event LogFunctionFlow(uint);
    uint public balance;
    function sendToAnother() public {
        balance += 10;
        emit LogFunctionFlow(balance);
    }
}
```

Somebody please guide me how to remove the warning message.

Zulfi.

Comment: It is just a warning. The analysis tool doesn't follow cross contracts calls, like the one to function `sendToAnother()`.

Comment: Please guide me how to solve this problem

Comment: There's no problem. It is just the tool not being capable to analyze contract calling to another. Just ignore the warning.